# BLE: can't change view onConnectionStateChange from BluetoothGattCallback

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to communicate between my HM-10 (BLE) module and my android app.
When the app is started, the ble connection is initiated and a dialog, which shows the current connection state, opens.

In my BluetoothGattCallback the onConnectionStateChange is fired correctly, however when I try update the state in the dialog (image and textview), nothing happens. Toast's don't show up either..

I'm opening the connection like this (from the main thread, not in a service or anything):

```
    public void connect(Context context, BluetoothCallback callback) {
        gatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, callback);
    }
```

Is the onConnectionStateChange callback still running on a different thread maybe? Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I got it working using a handler. Apparently the callback is still on another thread..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Bluetooth callbacks are by default sent from a Binder thread. You are not allowed to modify UI from Binder threads.